# Enterprise Library Exception Handling not triggering listeners with second HandleException call

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I'm seeing unexpected behaviour in our application which is using Enterprise Library 5 Exception Handling.

We have a try/catch which handles and rethrows the exception to the caller. The caller also does the same HandleException call.  However, the listeners are not getting executed and the second call is never written to any of our listeners (Log file, database, etc).  I find this behaviour unexpected.

To further test this, I even simplified the code so that when an exception occurs, I immidiately make 2 calls to handle Exception.

The first call executes our listeners and logs properly.  The second call does not execute our listener.  I also know that the listeners are not being triggered because we have a custom listener in which I set a breakpoint and it only gets triggered on the first HandleException call.

rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "UserInterfacePolicy");
rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "UserInterfacePolicy");

Is this expected behaviour?  I can't find any internet or document reference relating to this 'feature' of Enterprise Library.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post a complete example with code and configuration that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Nah.  I don't see that it would provide any value as the mechanism is in the underlying framework (entlib dll) code itself and not in configuration or custom code.  However, if your experience is different in your scenario then I think THAT would be important to know.